# How to use transformList method of AliasToBeanResultTransformer?

Tags: java, hibernate

Did someone knows how to use hibernate [ResultTransformer](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/transform/AliasToBeanResultTransformer.html)? I want to convert entity to dto. This is my code

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Person.class)
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("id",id));
PersonDto personDto = criteria.uniqueResult();
```

It throws a classCastException saying cannot cast Person to PersonDto.

Additional question:
This code works fine but why not the above code?

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Person.class);
List<PersonDto> personDtos = criteria.list();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to convert entities maybe you should use tool like dozer 
http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/usage.html

Example of using transformList

```
Query query = session.createQuery(""
                    + "Select DISTINCT VP.versionId as parent from VersionData VP "
                    + "INNER JOIN VP.zvitId ZP "
                    + "INNER JOIN ZP.childrens CH "
                    + "INNER JOIN CH.versions CP "
                    + "where CP.zvitId.zvitId = :idList and VP.dend IS NULL"
                    )
                    .setParameter("idList", id)
                    .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(ParentIdList.class));
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            List<ParentIdList> result = query.list();
```

Parent IdList has the same property name as returning values of query
    public class ParentIdList
    {
        private String parent;

```
    /**
     * @return the parents
     */
    public String getParent()
    {
        return parent;
    }

    /**
     * @param parents the parents to set
     */
    public void setParent(String parents)
    {
        this.parent = parents;
    }
    //getters, setters, hashcode, equals
}
```